# How to run 2 shell scripts from ramdisk?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, shell, kernel, scripts

I am attempting to setup my ramdisk to fire off 2 sets of scripts.
1 is ramdisk /sbin only, the others are user allowed scripts

```
# Check Properties
on property:dp.early_init.done=1
    chmod 0777 /data/dp_scripts/onearlyinit.sh
    exec /data/dp_scripts/onearlyinit.sh &
    start dp_early_init

on property:dp.init.done=1
    chmod 0777 /data/dp_scripts/oninit.sh
    exec /data/dp_scripts/oninit.sh &
    start dp_init

on property:dp.late_init.done=1
    chmod 0777 /data/dp_scripts/onlateinit.sh
    exec /data/dp_scripts/onlateinit.sh &
    start dp_late_init

on property:dp.post_fs.done=1
    chmod 0777 /data/dp_scripts/onpostfs.sh
    exec /data/dp_scripts/onpostfs.sh &
    start dp_post_fs

on property:dp.post_fs_data.done=1
    chmod 0777 /data/dp_scripts/onpostfsdata.sh
    exec /data/dp_scripts/onpostfsdata.sh &
    start dp_post_fs_data

on property:dp.boot.done=1
    chmod 0777 /data/dp_scripts/onboot.sh
    exec /data/dp_scripts/onboot.sh &
    start dp_boot

on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    chmod 0777 /data/dp_scripts/onpostboot.sh
    exec /data/dp_scripts/onpostboot.sh &
    export PATH /sbin:/system/bin
    start dp_post_boot

on property:sys.shutdown.requested=1
    chmod 0777 /data/dp_scripts/onshutdown.sh
    exec /data/dp_scripts/onshutdown.sh &
    start dp_shutdown

# DP Services
service dp_early_init /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onearlyinit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_init /sbin/bash /sbin/0/oninit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_late_init /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onlateinit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_post_fs /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onpostfs.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_post_fs_data /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onpostfsdata.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_boot /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onboot.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_post_boot /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onpostboot.sh
    class late_start
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_shutdown /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onshutdown.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot
```

While the services themselves all fire off, the execution of the `/data/dp_scripts/*` scripts never happens.

This is a lollipop kernel, running on a Note 3

How can I force the execution of `/data/dp_scripts/*` at the moments specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to do the trick

```
# Check Properties
on property:dp.early_init.done=1
    start dp_early_init
    start dpu_early_init

on property:dp.init.done=1
    start dp_init
    start dpu_init

on property:dp.late_init.done=1
    start dp_late_init
    start dpu_late_init

on property:dp.post_fs.done=1
    start dp_post_fs
    start dpu_post_fs

on property:dp.post_fs_data.done=1
    start dp_post_fs_data
    start dpu_post_fs_data

on property:dp.boot.done=1
    start dp_boot
    start dpu_boot

on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    export PATH /sbin:/system/bin
    start dp_post_boot
    start dpu_post_boot

on property:sys.shutdown.requested=1
    start dp_shutdown
    start dpu_shutdown

# DP User Services
service dpu_early_init /sbin/bash /data/dp_scripts/onearlyinit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dpu_init /sbin/bash /data/dp_scripts/oninit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dpu_late_init /sbin/bash /data/dp_scripts/onlateinit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dpu_post_fs /sbin/bash /data/dp_scripts/onpostfs.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dpu_post_fs_data /sbin/bash /data/dp_scripts/onpostfsdata.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dpu_boot /sbin/bash /data/dp_scripts/onboot.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dpu_post_boot /sbin/bash /data/dp_scripts/onpostboot.sh
    class late_start
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dpu_shutdown /sbin/bash /data/dp_scripts/onshutdown.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

# DP Services
service dp_early_init /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onearlyinit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_init /sbin/bash /sbin/0/oninit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_late_init /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onlateinit.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_post_fs /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onpostfs.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_post_fs_data /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onpostfsdata.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_boot /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onboot.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_post_boot /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onpostboot.sh
    class late_start
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot

service dp_shutdown /sbin/bash /sbin/0/onshutdown.sh
    user root
    disabled
    oneshot
```